# Translate JSON in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I'm currently doing this in a controller:

```
def index
  @orders = Order.all
  respond_to do |format| {
    format.html
    format.js { render json: @orders.as_json()
  }
end
```

I have a order state field. The values of this field are in English and need to be translated to Dutch. Problem is, the as_json call doesn't automatically translate the data to Dutch. The YML file and current and default locale all are working correctly. ( calling I18n.t works, but how does this work with as_json() ? )

Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking about adding an as_translated_json to ActiveRecord for my project - maybe pass a list of attributes that need translating, defaulting to all.  Did you come up with - or find a good solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can override as_json in your model and call i18n from that method.